how to create a custom IOS unnotificationTrigger with Swift?
I like to create a height notification trigger for my Swiftui app by subclassing UNNotificationTrigger. When I climb a mountain and reach the height of 2000 meters, I will get à notification on my apple device. Please advise me how.
i read the apple document and find no clue.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You cannot create your own UNNotificationTrigger subclasses.
You can only use the concrete subclasses provided by iOS:

UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger
UNCalendarNotificationTrigger
UNLocationNotificationTrigger

If you have always location permission and background location updates enabled you could, potentially, trigger a local notification when you determine that the current location is at or above your target altitude.
